# Allowing conditional actions upon tableview row select

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue

I want to allow a user to select a row, and given the relationship of that friend, a different action occurs upon row click. For example, if a friend, then chat opens, if not a friend, then can allow sending friend request,...etc.

At present, I have implemented the below, but on every row click, no matter the status of friend or not, the chat opens up and throws an error that the `friendChat` object of the resulting `IndividualChatController`:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

        // Ensure controller knows which dataset to pull from,
        // so detail view is correct
        let friendChat: Friend
        if searchController.active && searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
            friendChat = filterMappedFriends[indexPath.row]
        } else {
            friendChat = mappedFriends[indexPath.row]
        }

        // Now set the conditional cases: if a friend then chat, if user then friend request if not user then can invite them:
        if(friendChat.statusSort == 2) {
            performSegueWithIdentifier("showIndividualChat", sender: self)

            func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

                if segue.identifier == "showIndividualChat" {

                    let controller = segue.destinationViewController as! IndividualChatController
                        controller.friendChat = friendChat
                        controller.senderId = FeastGlobal.sharedInstance.userID
                        controller.senderDisplayName = FeastGlobal.sharedInstance.userName
                }
            }
        } else if (friendChat.statusSort == 1) {

            print("Can invite to be friend")

        } else if (friendChat.statusSort == 0) {

            print("Invite to Feast")

        }

}
```

Main.:

[image]

Close up on the segue name:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it doesn't work for the other statusSort cases? The other ones look fine but statusSort == 2 shouldn't work because you're defining prepareForSegue as a new nested function. I'm wondering if you're just seeing the problem for statusSort == 2 and mistaking it for the others?

The reason statusSort == 2 won't work is because you re-defined prepareForSegue as a nested function inside the condition, it needs to be a function of the view controller as an override. Put it on the same level as the override func tableView as another override.

As it stands now it's not going to be called and so you're performing the segue for statusSort == 2 without setting the parts of the destination view controller. That's why it's complaining about the friendChat, it's not set.

Like this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    // You're already doing this part.
}

// Move your prepareForSegue out here like this:
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Do your stuff here with the destination view controller. You have multiple options here to handle the upcoming segue properly.
    // Option 1: Use the segue identifier from your existing code so you can distinguish between multiple segues here.
    // <YOUR CODE HERE>
    // Option 2: If you segue to distinct view controllers, you can just check for the view controller type here. Either do this through optional downcast or use the "is" operator and then cast inside the conditional blocks. The former is shown below and is cleaner.
    if let someViewController: SomeViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? SomeViewController {
        // This is a segue headed to SomeViewController. Now we can set SomeViewController here. I'm just making up a bar here.
        let foo: Int = 1
        someViewController.bar = foo
    } else if let anotherViewController: AnotherViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? AnotherViewController {
        // Another segue headed to AnotherViewController.
        let foo: Int = 1
        anotherViewController.bar = foo
    }
}
```

Comment: If I implement your code, the other actions assume the use of the `Segue`, again throwing the error. You answer is incomplete

Comment: This answer is correct.  You should probably pass `friendChat` as the `sender` when you call `performSegueWithIdentifier` so that you can access it in `prepareForSegue`.  Make sure you don't have link from the table view cell's `action` to your next view controller in your storyboard

Comment: I put the comment there to tell you to put your stuff in there. My answer is complete, whether you want me to copy and paste the rest of your code in there or not.

EDIT: Here let me go even further then.

Comment: But I do not want all the rows to allow movement to another `ViewController`. As I outlined, if a friend row is clicked, then it opens to a `ViewController` for chatting, if not a friend, pon click it then simply triggers action on the server, no movement at all. Your answer is assuming I want every single row, upon click, to navigate to another `ViewController`, which I do not want to occur.

Answer (score 0):

You should not put prepareForSegue method in the didSelectRow method.
Doing that will cause prepareForSegueMethod not called.

This is wrong:

```
class YourClass: UITableViewController {

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        // Don't put in here
        func prepareForSegue(sgue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
            ...
        }
    }

}
```

Instead, put it directly inside your class:

```
class YourClass: UITableViewController {

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        ...
    }

    // Put in here
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        ...    
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I handle the selection of rows that are not supposed to go to another view but simply trigger a server action?

Comment: ie. I do not want all rows to move to a new view. Conditional on their data, they should not  do anything upon user selection. How is this achieved?

Comment: just check the data inside the didSelectRowAtIndexPathMethod. It won't go to another view unless you call performSegueWithIdentifier. Remember to remove the touch action in the storyboard

Comment: How do I remove the touch action?

Comment: See the picture in your post, when you select the cell, you can see the blue line (segue) between the screen, that's the default segue. Click the segue and delete it. 
Now you can make your custom segue by clicking your "FriendsViewController" on storyboard's navigation tree. Hold control and drag it to your "DetailViewController" choose show on the popup and give that segue an identifier "showDetail".

Now whenever you want to go to the detail screen, just call
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showDetail", sender: self);

Comment: But I do not want all the rows to allow movement to another `ViewControlle`r. As I outlined, if a friend row is clicked, then it opens to a `ViewController` for chatting, if not a friend, upon click it then simply triggers action on the server, no movement at all. Your answer is assuming I want every single row, upon click, to navigate to another `ViewController`, which I do not want to occur.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113538/discussion-between-sauron-and-edward-anthony).